# Trying Merge document with PDFMergerUtility in pdfbox 2.00

Tags: java, pdfbox

We have a PDF doc of 10 pages. We are in a need to rearrange the pages and split them into 3 or 4 documents. We were using Pdfbox Merge Document with 1.8.xx as like mergePdf.mergeDocuments() it working fine .now pdfbox version 2.0.0 the sequence is going wrong post rearranging  merging 10 pages  into 3 separate document.I have tried both setuptemp and setupmain. Both are not providing any positive inputs as well.

Pdfbox 1.8 code sample:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(sourceFile));
PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
splitter.setStartPage(fDStartPage);
splitter.setSplitAtPage((fDEndPage));
List<PDDocument> splittedDocuments = splitter.split(document);
PDFmerger.addSource(getInputStream(splittedDocuments.get(0)));
PDFmerger.setDestinationFileName(destinationFile);
PDFmerger.mergeDocuments();
```

PDFbox 2.0 code sample:

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filename));
pdfmerger.setDestinationFileName(mergedFileName);
Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
splitter.setStartPage(9);
splitter.setSplitAtPage(10);
List<PDDocument> document1 splitter.split(document);
InputStream is = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
document1.get(0).save(out);
byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
pdfmerger.addSource(is);
pdfmerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
document.close();
```

Comment: What does "getInputStream" do? Is the code segment shown one code or is it two alternatives that you tried? Can you share the PDF and explain what you expected and what happened instead? And what are the values of fDStartPage and fDEndPage?

Comment: code segment have two different code sample first one tried in PDFbox 1.8.Its working fine and second one tried in PDFbox2.0 it has above mentioned problems.

Comment: I tried the second code, and it produces one file with 2 pages, which are the original pages 9 and 10, which is what I expected (read the javadoc of the splitter methods). As source file, I used https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12649803/000364.pdf which has exactly 10 pages. Btw I don't understand what the merge is for, it does nothing, i.e. it merges 1 document. I don't understand how you expect this to be split in 3 parts, when you save only one file, and start the split at page 9 in a source file with 10 pages.